# Completing the square under a square root

Tags: substitution, hyperbolic-functions, completing-the-square

Trying to work through a problem that requires us to complete the square, then use a sinh substitution...but I need to start by remembering back to math from many years ago.

$$\int\sqrt{2x^2+3x+4} \ dx$$

Starting to complete the square I know the goal is to arrive at the form $(x+a)^2$ so I did the following

1. $$2(x^2+\frac{3}{2}x+2)$$
2. $$2(x^2+2\frac{3}{4}x+\frac{9}{16})$$
   because of $(x+\frac{3}{4})^2$

And then eventually I should arrive at
$$(x+\frac{3}{4})^2 + \frac{23}{16}$$

Is that leap I'm making correct? I can't figure out where the 2 went on the middle term and what becomes of the 2 I took out front. My professor explained that part of this becomes easier when you subtract a $\frac{9}{16} and a 2, but they just sort of get added to the end of the line which I can't figure out how.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Follow these guidelines to get help in this forum. It's particularly important that you share your own work and thoughts on the problem to show that you have made a serious effort by yourself before asking for help, and you're not just trying to get others to solve it for you.

Comment: In your case there is 2 in front of x^2 so your goal won't be acheived. [ If you multiply out $(x+a)^2+b$ you cannot match $2x^2$] Your form should be $2(x+a)^2+b.$